# $_SESSION Variable Validation Leads to Blank PHP Page / No Content

Tags: php, validation, session

Successful login on my login page should direct to a homepage (which it does - I double checked to see is the variables are set and they are when a correct username/password is entered). Otherwise, the login page should be private.

LOGIN PHP (works fine)

```
<?php
session_start();
require_once("../inc_files/Lesson_5_DB_Connection.php"); 
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

    $error_message= "";
    $user_name = "";
    $user_password= "";
    $_SESSION['username']="";
    $_SESSION['employeeNumber']="";

    if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {

        $user_name = $_POST['user'];
        $user_password= $_POST['pass'];



        // ADD QUERY TO CHECK IF USER/PASS COMBO IS CORRECT
        if(!empty($user_name) && !empty($user_password)) {

        $query = "SELECT * FROM employees WHERE username='$user_name' and password='$user_password'";

        $result = mysqli_query($dbc, $query)
            or die ('Error querying username/password request');

            if(mysqli_num_rows($result) == 1) {

             while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
                $_SESSION['username'] = $row['username'];
                $_SESSION['employeeNumber'] = $row['employeeNumber'];
             }

                 header("Location: /LESSON5/3%20-%20HOMEPAGE%20:%20WELCOME.php");
                exit;

            } // end if rows

            else {
                $error_message = "You were not able to log in";
            } // end else

        // Direct to other webpage

        } // end query

    } // end isset
?>
```

The homepage should only be visible if the $_SESSION variables are set. If the user is not logged in (session variables not set) then the homepage should redirect to the login page. Now, I added a validation to see if variables are not set (!isset). This validation keeps the page from showing any content. When I delete this validation the HTML shows up fine. When I delete the validation and echo the variable values I get the values returned.

It's just the `if(!isset($_SESSION['username']) && !isset($_SESSION['employeeNumber'])` keeping from showing any content on the page.

HOMEPAGE

```
<?php
    session_start();
    require_once("../inc_files/Lesson_5_DB_Connection.php");

    if(!isset($_SESSION['username']) && !isset($_SESSION['employeeNumber']) {

        header("Location: /LESSON5/1%20-%20LOGIN.php");
    }
?>

    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
          <meta charset="utf-8">
          <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="/LESSON5/5_Signup_CSS.css">
    </head>

    <body>
        <p><span id="logout"><a href="/LESSON5/4%20-%20LOGOUT%20PAGE.PHP">Logout</a></span></p>
        <hr>
        <h1>Welcome to my homepage! <br> You have successfully logged in.</h1>

    <?php
        mysqli_close($dbc);
    ?>

    </body>

    </html>
```

Is there any reason why that validation is keeping the PHP from showing the HTML(if user login is correct) or redirect the page(if user not logged in)?

Comment: Typo, closing paranthesis missing: `if(!isset($_SESSION['username']) && !isset($_SESSION['employeeNumber']))`.

Comment: I believe that you get blank page due to php error (since your server might configured to `error_display` false). Add "parent" brackets to your condition: `if( (condition A) && (condition B) )`

Comment: If you're not using an IDE that highlights syntax errors, you should. You really shouldn't have to waste the time of hundreds of SO readers with trivial syntax errors like this.

Comment: @Barmar agreed. My test editor does not highlight errors, I will switch to a better text editor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically error is in your php `if` condition. One parenthesis is missing. change like this:-

```
if(!isset($_SESSION['username']) && !isset($_SESSION['employeeNumber']))
```

Note:- try to add `error_reporing` at the top of your all php pages so that you can get php errors if happen. check the manual of `error_reporing` on php site. Thanks.

If you are working on local server you can change your `php.ini` settings for this.

You can get how to change `php.ini` setting on google easily.

`ini_set` is function of php is for this purpose if you want to do it programmatically not with php.ini directly.

Comment: @isha did you get the solution or not?